# detect changes in MS word document programatically

Tags: ms-word

How to detect changes in particular section of a word document. There could be many changes in other part of the document which should be ignored. I need to see if the doc is changed in the particular section only. Is there any way of finding this out?

Answer (score 0):

The object `WordApplication` has the property `MODIFIED`, so, you can to use:

```
if xxxx.Modified then showmessage( 'doc edited' )
```

Comment: This will show that the doc is modified, but not in which section.